# Why do they use "in" like random in the sentences?

Tags: prepositions

How can I understand the usage of *in* which comes after *have* in the sentence below?

From [Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's *Sherlock Holmes in A Study in Scarlett*, Chapter 3](http://www.utlm.org/onlinebooks/sherlockholmes_astudyinscarlet_part1chap3.htm):

> There still remained some lurking suspicion in my mind, however, that the whole thing was a prearranged episode, intended to dazzle me, though what earthly object he could have **in** taking me in was past my comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence you have to identify the two collocations for the preposition "in" and compare it to another colocation having the same meaning.

1-  "...Though what earthly object he could have in = what was his reason for

```
   Examples  -  What is your object in asking questions about English? =
                What is your reason for asking questions about English.
```

2-  - taking me "in" ( meaning = accepting / receiving  me).

3-  The simplified meaning of the sentence is :
     the person wonders what was that male character´s object in accepting      him/her.

Comment: Quite right except, looking at the context, I think "taking me in" means something else akin to deceiving/duping him.

Answer (score 0):

I see the usage as a way of inserting a thought or thoughts within another thought.

His object in taking me in was purely charitable.
My purpose in pulling the trigger was to kill the rat.
In painting this picture, I exposed contemporary vanities, used a lot of paint and made a lot of money.

I believe the usage is based on the following construction. In [gerund][modifier of the gerund][purpose or consequnce of the gerundial action]. The modifier may also appear before the gerund.

In making these remarks I try to help but please forgive my vagueness: others may explain this more clearly than I.